# How to calculate certain chars from a string

Tags: javascript, validation, eval, luhn

i'm looking for this since yesterday, already searched a lot but didn't find any answer for exactly what I need. If you find any, just tell me, i'll appreciate and close this question :)

What I want is:

```
-> If there are an even number of digits, double every other digit starting with the first

-> If there are an odd number of digits, double every other digit starting with the second.
```

This is what I did so far:

```
function validate(n){
            var num = n.toString(); // THIS COULD BE AN ARRAY OR WHATEVER

            if (eval(num%2==0)) { // IF HAS EVEN NUMBER OF DIGITS
                for (var i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
                    if (num.charAt(i) === num.charAt(0)) {
                        eval(num.charAt(i)*=2);
                    }
                }
                console.log(num);
            } else { // IF HAS ODD NUMBER OF DIGITS
                for (var i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
                    if (num.charAt(i) === num.charAt(1)) {
                        eval(num.charAt(i)*=2);
                    }                       
                }
                console.log(num);
            }
        }

        validate(1234516178);
```

Examples:

```
1714 => [1*, 7, 1*, 4] => [2, 7, 2, 4]

891 => [8, 9*, 1] => [8, 18, 1]
```

Hope I was clear. Can someone help on this? Appreciate!

Comment: please add some examples

Comment: WHat do you mean by `double the first number, and all numbers equal to the first one??`

Comment: Javascript's `.splice` could be used here, `.split`ing the strings to arrays also will help.

Comment: The purpose is to validate a credit card number using the Luhn Algorithm. I added some examples.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? What do you think the difference is between `eval(num%2 == 0)` and just `num%2 == 0`?

Comment: There's nothing in the Luhn algorithm about doubling only the digits that are the same as the first or second digit. There's also nothing special about odd and even numbers -- what matters is whether the number of digits is odd or even. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: I suggest slowing down and reading some introductory materials about Javascript. You could do worse than taking a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript. You'll also need to do a lot of debugging, so I suggest you familiarize yourself intimately with debugging tools such as the Chrome devtools, and arm yourself with the knowedge in guides to debugging such as http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: It seems like this problem statement is wrong, where did it come from? *If number is even: double the first number, and all numbers equal to the first one.* It seems like it should be "if number is even: double the first **digit**.*

Comment: @Barmar I'm using eval because I had to convert the int into a string. About the rest, i'm doing a codewars.com exercise. And that's what they ask. I'll quote: "If there are an even number of digits, double every other digit starting with the first, and if there are an odd number of digits, double every other digit starting with the second."

Comment: @torazaburo Why you say that? I read a lot of materials about Javascript. But yeah, i'm still learning, otherwise I wasn't asking this... Thanks for the links though...

Comment: @jbarradas You don't use `eval` to convert an int to a string, use `num.toString()`. And the exercise says what I said: "even number of digits". That's not the same as the number being even. `4321` is an odd number with an even number of digits.

Comment: @Barmar I used `eval` because I converted the int into a string... So, for what I read, to calculate a string `eval` is needed.. About the even story, sorry for my english. It seems most of people understood anyway.. but you're right on that.

Comment: @jbarradas Your use of `eval` shows there's some kind of gap. Why write `eval(a += 1)`? This will just evaluate `a += 1`, then pass the result of `2` or whatever to eval, which will evaluate it as, umm, `2`, then throw away the result. At the end of the day all that has happened is that `a` has been incremented, which would have happened without the `eval`.

Comment: @torazaburo because that `a` is a string. And not a number.

Comment: @jbarradas Then you should write `a = Number(a) + 1;`

Comment: @jbarradas Do **not** use `eval` to convert strings to numbers. Use `Number` or `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: @Barmar Man, i'm not using `eval` to convert anything. I'm using it 'because' I converted a number into a string before. Then, and only AFTER converting it into a string, I used `eval` to calculate. Either way, thanks for your help but this questions has been answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you. It utilizes an array with the values and iterates over the values to change.

```js
function validate(n) {
    var array = n.toString().split('').map(Number),
        number = n % 2 ? array[1] : array[0];

    return array.map(function (a) {
        return a === number ? 2 * a : a;
    });
}

function print(o) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

print(validate(1234516178));
print(validate(1714)); // => [1*, 7, 1*, 4] => [2, 7, 2, 4]
print(validate(891));  // => [8, 9*, 1] => [8, 18, 1]
```

Comment: This is a bit advanced for me now. But it seems the best one. I'll test all answers and try to decrypt yours :p and then come back to set a 'right answer'. Thanks for your kind help! :)

Comment: Can you tell me how does it call this type of expression: `return conditional ? false : true;` So I can search about it? Thanks!

Comment: it's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) or a conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function validate(n) {
    n = n.toString();
    var isEven = (parseInt(n, 10) % 2 === 0);
    var digits = n.split("");

    // Strings to numbers
    digits.forEach(function(digit, index) {
        digits[index] = parseInt(digit, 10);
    });

    if(isEven) {
        var firstDigit = digits[0];
        digits.forEach(function(digit, index) {
            console.log(digit);
            if(digit === firstDigit) {
                digits[index] *= 2;
            }
        });
    } else {
        var secondDigit = digits[1];
        digits.forEach(function(digit, index) {
            if(digit === secondDigit) {
                digits[index] *= 2;
            }
        });
    }
    return JSON.stringify(digits);
}
```

This can be of course be made better with including more conditions and leaving just a single forEach

Answer (score 0):

You dont need strings to do that

```js
function validate(s){
  var a = parseInt(s);
  var b = 0;
  var odd = (a+'').length %2//true;
  //var summ = 0;
  while(a>=1){
    var b = Math.floor(a%10);
    var c = odd?b: b*2//<10? b*2 : b*2-9;
    //summ += c;
    odd = !odd;
    a = a/10;
    
    //output
    $('input').after('+'+c)
    
  }
  //output
  $('input').after('<br>')//.after(summ).after('<br> summ: ')
//return summ%10
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="validate($('input').val())">validate</button>
<input>
```

Comment: test it with numbers 1234516178 or 891. It does not give correct answer.